# Twitter share photo feature for iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, twitter

I currently have an iOS app with facebook integration that allows users to post their photos to facebook.

I want to add twitter integration as well, but I couldn't find any information about it. I read somewhere that it's now possible to upload photos directly to twitter, without an external site, such as twitpic.

Does twitter provide an iOS API in the same manner that [facebook provides their APIs](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)?

I looked over [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/), but it has tons of features that I don't need and the workflow of uploading a photo is customized in my app. Worst case, I'll copy-paste some code from ShareKit, but I'm not sure it even has the ability to share a photo to twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter doesn't provide it's own photo sharing API. You have to upload your photos somewhere (on your own server, twitpic, etc.) and get the link and post the photo's link along with the tweet text.

I haven't used twitpic before but it looks like they have their own API that you can check out [here](http://dev.twitpic.com/).

If you're uploading them to your own server, you should use bit.ly's api to shorten the URL's of the photo links to provide more tweet text space. Info on bit.ly's API is [here](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation).

Comment: thanks, i'll check twitpic API. I thought there was something easier