# iPhone:How to upload photos on twitter using xAuth or OAuth authentication?

Tags: iphone, twitter, photo-upload

Is there any way to upload photo on Twitter using xAuth or OAuth authentication in iPhone? Is there any sample code or framework I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588583/twitter-share-photo-feature-for-ios/6590755#6590755) it's not possible to upload images directly to Twitter. You need to yup load to some other photo-sharing site, and link to it in your Twitter post. I'd recommend looking into imgur. They [have an API](http://api.imgur.com/) which you may be able to use.

Answer (score 0):

Photo sharing uplaod feature is now available on Twitter, but there's no stable library for iphone yet released.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy in iOS 5.

Just include the header file `#import "Twitter/Twitter.h"` and add the framework Twitter.framework in the project..

Then add the lines below for a button action:

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweeter =    [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
[tweeter setInitialText:@"message"]; // for posting text
[tweeter addImage:image];            // for posting image
[self presentModalViewController:tweeter animated:YES];
```